# Inserting data into mongodb cluster using pymongo: getting Bad Auth authentication error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to insert data into mongodb cluster using pymongo. But I'm getting Bad Auth authentication error.

```
client=pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-vt8ej.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-vt8ej.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-vt8ej.mongodb.net:27017/xbee_data?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin")

db=client.xbee_data
post = {"author": "Mike",
         "text": "My first blog post!",
         "tags": ["mongodb", "python", "pymongo"]
         }
nodes = db.nodes
post_id=db.nodes.insert_one(post)
```

Comment: Bad Auth error can be as a result of many things. First are you able to read from the collection? If yes, do you have the right role/privilege assigned to your user to write to the `xbee_data` collection? If no, can you that you have the necessary credentials to establish a connection to the cluster?

Comment: no,i'm not able to read the data too. can you please suggest me how to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Venkatesh M!

I can see that you are trying to authenticate your 'username' on the 'admin' collection. Are you sure this user is on this database? Perhaps you must authenticate it on the xbee_data database.

Beyond that, I have noticed that you are inserting in this way:
post_id = db.nodes.insert_one(post)
When the right way would be:
post_id = nodes.insert_one(post)

Hope this help you!